# How can I include a ManyToMany field into django admin fieldsets?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have two models:

## Python 3.7

```
class ClassOne(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='')

class ClassTwo(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='')
     class_ones = models.ManyToManyField(ClassOne)
```

Now I would like to show ClassOne in django-admin with all ClassTwo's listed. I already tried to create a Tabular (admin.TabularInline) or create a method in ClassOne as following:

```
def get_class_twos(self):
     return self.classtwo_set.all()
```

and include that method in the fieldsets, but that did not work either. Neither did directly putting `classtwo_set.all()` or `classtwo_set` in the fieldset list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first should define TabularInline:

```
class ClassOneInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ClassTwo.classone.through
    form = ClassOneForm
```

Then add it to admin class for ClassTwo:

```
class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (ClassOneInLine,)
```

And don't forget to register admin.

Comment: Do you know a way how to do it the other way around? So the Inline Class is for ClassTwo and the main admin class is for ClassOne?